# Why is the default behavior for Ant Copy to not overwrite files based on time-stamp?

Tags: ant, timestamp

This really burned me recently: [Burned by Ant Copy...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948689/jndi-namenotfoundexception-after-tomcat-8-upgrade)

I am just surprised this is the default behavior for Ant Copy. Does anyone know why this rule stands? Is it a hated default but not trivial to change because it would break old code? Is it a good default but I just don't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant was developed to be a build system, not a general-purpose scripting language.  Only copying files that are out of date is an important part of a build system in order to have high performance incremental builds (changing a subset of input files should only execute the minimum number of actions required to complete the build).